# I want to change my label colour according to text in response from server

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am using For loop in CellForRowat Indexpath  to change colour but it showing me error how can I resolve it. and I put the correct key value

> Error(Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040000f6680'

```swift
for all in arrayForType!
{
    let type = (all as AnyObject).object(forKey: "type") as! String
    print(type)

    if type == "Send"
    {
        cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where you're getting error

Comment: you can set in  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) method.Inside this method, you can set the conditions and can set the background color.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in that for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolvedly issue and it is correct way to do it.

```
let type = (arrayForType[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "type") as! String
print(type)

if type == "Send"
{
    cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
else
{
    cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `AnyObject` don't have `.object(forKey: #"")` method, objectForKey method is a method of `NSDictionary` that is your crash reason

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1414347-objectforkey

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in this line:

```
let type = (all as AnyObject).object(forKey: "type") as! String
```

You're treating `all` as `AnyObject` (which is redundant, by the way), but the method you call on it - `object(forKey: String)` - is a method of `NSDictionary` class

instead, try

```
guard let array = arrayForType else { return }
for all in array
{
    guard let dict = all as? NSDictionary else { continue }
    guard let type = dict.object(forKey: "type") as? String else { continue }

    print(type)

    if type == "Send"
    {
        cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }    
}
```

Also, avoid force-unwrapping optionals (the `!` operator), although this was not the cause of crash in your case

Comment: Why you downrate my answer? your answer is same... :))

Comment: @JabaOdishelashvili Your answer has nothing to do with the actual problem, which is calling `NSDictionary` method on `AnyObject`.

Comment: but i have write it in safe way... your answer is same... except you cast as dictionary before...

Answer (score -1):

you should always try to avoid implicitly unwrap, especially when you work data fetched from server. try to use Optional Binding to achieve more safecity. just like that

```
guard let arrayForType = arrayForType as? [NSDictionary] else { return }
for all in arrayForType {
    if let type = all.object(forKey: "type") as? String, type == "Send" {
        cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = .red
    } else {
        cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with force unwrapping a nil value

Comment: Error message is about invalid argument at this line:
let type = (all as AnyObject).object(forKey: "type") as! String

optional binding avoid crash....

Comment: @JabaOdishelashvili the error message clearly says `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. If unwrapping nil was the issue, the error would say `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`